# Ubuntu 20.04 - files on network share appear as folders

Tags: networking, files, samba, gui, shared-folders

After installing 20.04 (with Gnome desktop env), when I navigate through the GUI to my network share, all of the files appear as directories and I am unable to download/copy them to my local host.  When I attempt to copy the folder (still in the UI), I received the following error message:
[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFlhC.png) (Error while copying. There was an error reading the folder "filename.txt". No such file or directory)

When I attempt to cat a file after navigating to the share via CLI, I receive the following output: cat: filename.txt: Is a directory

When I attempt ls -la, all of the files show as directories.

When I attempt more filename.txt, the output is: filename.txt: directory

Prior to accessing my shared drive, I had to modify the smb.conf file to include "client min protocol = CORE" in order to even access the shared drive.

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1872476 And here is the referenced PPA t fix it: https://launchpad.net/~sergiodj/+archive/ubuntu/samba-bug1872476-v2

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue... and I solved this by :

The files shown as **folders** or **directories** will show `user.DOSATTRIB` on `getfattr your_file_name` command. for example,

```
:~/$ getfattr riscv.dts
# file: riscv.dts
user.DOSATTRIB
```

To remove that use `setfattr -x user.DOSATTRIB your_file_name`. for example,

```
:~/$ setfattr -x user.DOSATTRIB riscv.dts 
:~/$ getfattr riscv.dts
```

This worked for me. for multiple files, use

```
find . -type f -exec setfattr -x user.DOSATTRIB "{}" \;
```

Hope this helps.