# Ubuntu 20.04 can't access my dlink sharecenter

Tags: networking, mount, samba, nas

My Ubuntu 20.04 does not access the windows network (D-link NAS-320L Share center), the error is the following:

`Failed to mount the windows share: Connection termination caused by software.`

In previous distros everything was normal.

Another post solved the problem adding the line
`client min protocol = NT1` in `smb.conf` file.

This works, but partially: I can browse the directory tree, but some files are seen like a directory and I receive an error trying to access them.

Comment: See my answer here please: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238507/upgraded-to-ubuntu-20-04-unable-to-access-older-nas-and-samba-servers

Comment: When you say "and I receive an error trying to access them" what is the error?

Comment: I followed the guide to install the PPA "fix"
in the meantime another post appeared (then removed, why?) indicating the fix present in focal-proposed so I updated from there:

`samba/focal-proposed,now 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installato]`

It now works properly.
Thank you all, also for formatting
P.S. the error received trying to access directory files was something like this:

`impossible to show the content of this location inpossible to find <file name> maybe it was recently eliminated`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`showmount -e 192.168.1.10 (ip address D-Link ShareCenter)`

Export list for IP's allowed:

`/mnt/HD/HD_b2 192.168.1.5`

`/mnt/HD/HD_a2 192.168.1.5`

and for mounting via nfs:

`sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.10:/mnt/HD/HD_a2  /HD1`

(`/HD1` should exist)

Answer (score 0):

The other option has been tested and works.

Add this line to /etc/samba/smb.conf

`client min protocol = NT1`

and restart:

`/etc/init.d/smbd restart`